# Firebase Desktop(or System Tray) Notifications from AppScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-apps-script, firebase-cloud-messaging

I had a frontend app that could subscribe to push notification topics via server-key. Firebase has discontinued this method and now requires a backend in Node, Java, .NET, C++, etc. However this is not possible as of now, and I have been sending clientTokens that need to subscribe to a topic to a Google AppScript endpoint, that stores them in a Sheet.

Now I have been **unable to find** how to use **Firebase Messaging from within AppScript** to create topics and subscribe users to them. I know it is possible for subscribing via the Admin SDK, which from my knowledge is not available in AppScripts.

Please guide.

Edit: I understand that we can only ever send browser push-notifications, and that depending on the browser and user settings, the notification would be visible if the browser is allowed to show desktop notifications, but that is a different topic.